# Bumblebee: How to fix the "Screen 1 deleted"-Error

Tags: x11, xorg, nvidia, bumblebee, optimus

I've installed on my notebook with **a primary Intel and a secondary Nvidia-GPU** *bumblebee* and the *nvidia-driver*.

I've installed the proprietary bumblebee (*bumblebee-nvidia* and *primus*) as well as the nvidia driver (*nvidia-driver*).

Unfortunately, every time I try to use the **optirun**-command, I run into the following error:

```
[  940.032794] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error:
               [XORG] (EE) Screen 1 deleted
               because of no matching config section.

[  940.032839] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

Why is this appearing? I've not separated */etc/X11/xorg.conf*-file where I've entered a screen 1 section or so.

OS and Kernel: Debian (4.6.0-1-amd64)

`dmesg` output **after** running `optirun glxinfo`:

```
[   60.060368] bbswitch: enabling discrete graphics
[   60.139924] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[   60.139930] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   60.148818] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20150116 for 0000:02:00.0 on minor 1
[   60.148822] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  352.79  Wed Jan 13 16:17:53 PST 2016
[   82.677037] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 6h 59min 17.494951s random time.
```

Additional my log-File-Dump from `/var/log/Xorg.8.log`: http://pastebin.com/raw/RbB5hg6h

Comment: Which distribution do you use? Can you post your dmesg after trying optirun?

Comment: @maxf Sure. I've just added some additional infos.

Comment: Okay. Looks good so far. Can you post the log of bumblebee's X server (i.e. /var/log/Xorg.8.log)?

Comment: Okay, I've added a link to the log-file-dump.

Comment: Did you modify /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia?

Comment: @maxf No I did't :/

Comment: Okay, I have one more idea: Please find your NVIDIA card's bus id in lspci (e.g. "01:00.0) and specify it in /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia like this: BusID "PCI:01:00:0". Reboot, try again and see if the Xorg log now looks different.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem of "Screen 1 deleted" on Debian testing with 4.9 kernel. I resolved adding the following lines to `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` as described here https://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Default Screen"
    Device "DiscreteNvidia"
EndSection
```

Eventually try also to set the BusID manually in the same file, finding it with `lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'`.